# from text to new row

Tags: sql, loops, text, sas, row

I have text:
[{crmId: 270294251239318446711736, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 109338771587264730348439, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 105563037561893625234667, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 529342335726661326310295, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 102928808219759468645267, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 446627936599178084266781, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 1206246190076409102049055, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 1208925742523269613394857, zapłacone faktury:0}]

I want crmid:
270294251239318446711736
109338771587264730348439
105563037561893625234667
529342335726661326310295
102928808219759468645267
446627936599178084266781
1206246190076409102049055
1208925742523269613394857

In this case is 7 id in new row but their number and length may vary

Comment: Welcome :-) Please be more specific about how your data is strucured. Do you have 1 obs with a long string? I can't tell.

Comment: in this sample is one but in table are thousands :)

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
have="[{crmId: 270294251239318446711736, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 109338771587264730348439, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 105563037561893625234667, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 529342335726661326310295, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 102928808219759468645267, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 446627936599178084266781, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 1206246190076409102049055, zapłacone faktury:0}, {crmId: 1208925742523269613394857, zapłacone faktury:0}]";
run;

data want;
 set have;
 pid=prxparse('/(?<=crmId:)\s*\d+/i');
s=1;e=length(have);
 call prxnext(pid,s,e,have,p,l);
 do while(p>0);
crmId=substr(have,p,l);
output;
call prxnext(pid,s,e,have,p,l);
 end;
 keep crmId;
run;
```